# After click on css class get src of closest iframe

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have multiple embedded youtube videos in my HTML so When the user clicks on the CSS class `.vma_overlay` I want to get the src of the closest iframe.

I have tried the following but it's not working:

```js
$(".vma_overlay").click(function() {
  data = $(event.target).closest('.vma_iFramePopup').attr("src");
  
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class=" ">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="sizer" style="width:100%">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item vma_iFramePopup" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/w5ln_-A3aw0?enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A57299" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen="" data-gtm-yt-inspected-9256558_25="true"
            id="874685300"></iframe>
          <div class="vma_overlay visible-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#vma_ModalBox"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Any help to push me in the right direction would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iframe isn't a parent element of `.vma_overlay` that why `closest()` will not find it, it's a "sibling" instead so you could use the jQuery **[`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** method like:

```
 data = $(event.target).siblings('.vma_iFramePopup').attr("src");
```

```js
$(".vma_overlay").click(function() {
  data = $(event.target).siblings('.vma_iFramePopup').attr("src");
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class=" ">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="sizer" style="width:100%">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item vma_iFramePopup" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/w5ln_-A3aw0?enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A57299" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen="" data-gtm-yt-inspected-9256558_25="true"
            id="874685300"></iframe>
          <div class="vma_overlay visible-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#vma_ModalBox">CLICK ME</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, evidently I failed to understand what closest does/is.

Answer (score 0):

closest won't work here :

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

try `siblings()` https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$(".vma_overlay").click(function (event) {
    data = $(event.target).parent().find('iframe.vma_iFramePopup').attr("src"); 
    console.log(data);
});
```